# close css tooltip on touchdevises

Tags: css, mobile, touch, tooltip

Im creating a css only tooltip for my new website project.
This tooltip shows right on touchdevises. The only problem is that touchdevises can't close the tooltip.

How can I modify the code that touchscreen users can close the tooltip if they touch somewhere around the tooltip? Or maybe if they touch on the tooltip visible text link?

I just want to use css if possible.

The CSS that I have:

```
a.tooltip {outline:none;}
a.tooltip strong {line-height:30px;}
a.tooltip:hover {text-decoration:none; cursor: help;} 
a.tooltip span {
z-index:10;display:none; padding:14px 20px;
margin-top:-30px; margin-left:28px;
width:220px; line-height:17px;
}

a.tooltip:hover span{
display:inline; position:absolute; color:#373535;
border:2px solid #D3D3D3; background:#fffFff;}

/*CSS3 extras*/
a.tooltip span
{
border-radius:5px;
-moz-border-radius: 5px;
-webkit-border-radius: 5px;

-moz-box-shadow: 1px 1px 8px #CCC;
-webkit-box-shadow: 1px 1px 8px #CCC;
box-shadow: 1px 1px 8px #CCC;
}
```

This is the html:

```
<a href="#" class="tooltip">Normal Text<span><strong>Tooltip title</strong><br />This would be the content of the tooltip.</span></a>
```

Thanks for help me out guys!

Regards, Dylan

Answer (score 0):

I got no problems as u describet but i tryed this and it works even better on my device. So check it that helps you.

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/GLORIEN/9R83P/)

HTML:

```
<a href="#" class="tooltip">
    Normal Text
</a>    
<span>
    <strong>Tooltip title</strong><br />
    This would be the content of the tooltip.
</span>
```

CSS:

```
a.tooltip {
    outline:none;
}

a.tooltip strong {
    line-height:30px;
}

a.tooltip:hover {
    text-decoration:none;
    cursor: help;
} 

span {
    z-index:10;display:none; 
    padding:14px 20px;
    margin-top:-30px; 
    margin-left:28px;
    width:220px; 
    line-height:17px;
}

a.tooltip:hover + span{
display:inline; position:absolute; color:#373535;
border:2px solid #D3D3D3; background:#fffFff;}

/*CSS3 extras*/
span {
    border-radius:5px;
    -moz-border-radius: 5px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
    -moz-box-shadow: 1px 1px 8px #CCC;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 1px 1px 8px #CCC;
    box-shadow: 1px 1px 8px #CCC;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. I used your code. but some text will disapear..  You can check the tooltip under this link on your touch devise: [link](http://www.ringvilla.de/Other/loodsmans-welvaren/arrangementen.php)

Comment: Of cause, you need to change it to your needs. All i did is to move the span out of the <a> tag. And select it with + that means the former element will activate on hover the immediate element after it...

Comment: I'm not sure if you may not remove the href auto of the a or replace it because the page will always jump or use the target fix... (happens on my mobile)